# Making a footer that has small div boxes inside of it responsive to the size of the browser window

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Within a footer there are 4 small boxes (created with divs that have a red border around them) and they all need to be made responsive to the width of the browser window as it is re-sized. They need to be centered and have an equal percentage space in between each other no matter what the window size is.

Like this: http://s7.postimg.org/tvmmw91jf/theboxes.png

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NightSpark/1L5027qr/

```css
#footer {
 width: 100%;
 clear: both;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: black;
 opacity: 0.7;
 height: 200px;
}

#fbox1 {
 border: 5px outset #ea2f2f;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: inline-block;
 float: left;
}

#fbox2 {
 border: 5px outset #ea2f2f;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: inline-block;
 float: left;
}

#fbox3 {
 border: 5px outset #ea2f2f;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: inline-block;
 float: left;
}

#fbox4 {
 border: 5px outset #ea2f2f;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: inline-block;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="footer">
 <div id="fbox1">
 </div>
 <div id="fbox2">
 </div>
 <div id="fbox3">
 </div>
 <div id="fbox4">
 </div>
<div>
</body>
```

**Update:** I put in a clearer illustration above than the one I had at first.

Comment: Is javascript permitted?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing you could do to center the elements is using **CSS Flexbox**.

Here's the **HTML** :

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="fbox1">
    </div>
    <div id="fbox2">
    </div>
    <div id="fbox3">
    </div>
    <div id="fbox4">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the **CSS** :

```
#footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    clear: both;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    height: 200px;
}

#fbox1 {
    border: 5px outset #ea2f2f;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: inline-block;
}

#fbox2 {
    border: 5px outset #ea2f2f;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: inline-block;
}

#fbox3 {
    border: 5px outset #ea2f2f;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: inline-block;
}

#fbox4 {
    border: 5px outset #ea2f2f;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: inline-block;
}
```

Here's a Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/1L5027qr/1/

Comment: Nice, i did not know flex property! Useful :-)

Comment: It's a nice way to position elements. You can even do vertical center way more easily than any other way.

Comment: Thanks for the IE patch. Is there any way to center the boxes in the middle of the footer and make all their margins on the left and right be an equal space away from each other? (See image in op)

Comment: Here is it with the elements centered and equal spaces away from each other. http://jsfiddle.net/1L5027qr/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a 25% width around each div.

```
<div id="footer">
  <div style="width:25%;display:inline-block;text-align:center;">
    <div id="fbox1">
    </div>
  </div><div style="width:25%;display:inline-block;text-align:center;">
    <div id="fbox2">
    </div>
  </div><div style="width:25%;display:inline-block;text-align:center;">
    <div id="fbox3">
    </div>
  </div><div style="width:25%;display:inline-block;text-align:center;">
    <div id="fbox4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to modify the mark-up a little:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="fbox1" class="outer">
        <div class="inner">...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="fbox2" class="outer">
        <div class="inner">...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="fbox3" class="outer">
        <div class="inner">...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="fbox4" class="outer">
        <div class="inner">...</div>
    </div>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    clear:both;
}
#footer .outer {
    width: calc(100% / 4 - 4px);
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}
#footer .inner {
    border: 5px outset #ea2f2f;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/simbunch/wcvb88yg/